# Can I edit my role within my team?

Tags: support, status-completed, old-teams

I've just joined a team and I had to fill in my 'role' as part of registering:

[image: What's your role on the team?]

Is there a way to edit this afterwards? I can't see a way, nor can I see a way to leave and re-join. Thanks!

Comment: Nope - this will integrate with the profile later and we messed up forgetting it in the interim. Josh and Geoff are working on deploying a UI for this right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can now edit your role on the "Members" tab.

[image: editing role]

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you can't, but we will fix this very soon.